# Ruby: using .send within a method behaves differently than calling it outside

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write a little snippet for my Rails app that checks if any tags are present for an object.

I have the following code:

```
def any_tags_present?(obj,*tags)
  tags ||= %w(person city country other)
  tags.any? { |tag| obj.send("#{tag}_list").present? }
end
```

running `tags.any? { |tag| obj.send("#{tag}_list").present? }` will return true if I call it directly:

```
obj = Article.first
tags ||= %w(person city country other)
tags.any? { |tag| obj.send("#{tag}_list").present? }

=> true
```

but if I call it with `any_tags_present?(Article.first)` I get false:

```
obj = Article.first
any_tags_present?(obj)

=> false
```

What gives?

Comment: I think you are not passing tags to #any_tags_present? method.If you have a situation where #any_tags_present? may or may not get tags, then use a default argument with nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can something like

```
def any_tags_present?(obj, tags=nil)
  tags ||= %w(person city country other)
  tags.any? { |tag| obj.send("#{tag}_list").present? }
end

obj = Article.first
any_tags_present?(obj)
```

So if you don't pass tags then it gets initialized by `%w(person city country other)`

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) I stupidly assumed *tags would have the same behavior as tags=nil but apparently that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line `tags ||= %w(person city country other)`. It doesn't get (re)assigned, because `tags` will be an empty `Array` (`[]`) and not `nil`. Possible solutions are just taking an default argument of `nil` and passing in an `Array` or checking if `tags` is empty.